# Check if std_logic_vector is contiguous

Tags: logic, vhdl

Say I have an arbitrary std_logic_vector, and I need to make sure that if it contains ones, all of the ones are clumped together. So

`1111 => true`

`0011 => true`

`0110 => true`

`1011 => false`

I have got ideas like count total zeros, count leading zeros and count trailing zeros and make sure that total_zeros = leading_zeros + trailing_zeros. But this feels very inefficient, it kindof feels like there should be a simple logic function to solve this. Is there such a function?

Comment: Its not a homework question.

Answer (score 0):

A Moore Finite State Machine (FSM) is a good way to solve this problem. The following FSM takes data bits one by one and outputs whether your condition (trapped ones) holds or not.

[image: FSM]

S0: Initial state
S1: Only 0s
S2: Only 1s or 1s following possible 0s
S3: Some zeros at the end
F: Fail state

Once all the data bits are fed, you can take the output corresponding to the current state.

Comment: This would only work if the data arriving is serial. It wont work so well with parrallel data busses.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such function. I would do it in this way (with data_i, data_o being "downto" vectors):

```
process(data_i)
    variable index_high : natural;
    variable index_low  : natural;
begin
    data_o <= data_i;
    index_high := 0;
    index_low  := 0;
    for i in data_i'range loop
        if index_high=0 then
            if data_i(i)='1'then
                index_high := i;
                index_low  := i;
            end if;
        else
            if data_i(i)='1' then
                index_low := i;
            end if;
        end if;
    end loop;
    for i in data_i'range loop
        if i<index_high and i>index_low then
            data_o(i) <= '1';
        end if;
    end loop;
end process;
```

Comment: Why does `data_o` have multiple bits?

Comment: @Tricky Because as I understood the question, the zeros between the leftmost 1 and the rightmost 1 shall be switched to one at data_o.

Answer (score 0):

This answer should work with vectors of any length. You need to use variables and the exit statement to exit a loop. Here is the sample code. I ran the code through simulation with vectors of 4 and 5 bits and it worked. It should work for any other sized vectors.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
USE IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
USE IEEE.std_logic_UNSIGNED.all;
USE ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity detect_contiguous is
  generic (
    num_bits_g : INTEGER
  );
  port (
    data_i    : in  std_logic_vector(num_bits_g-1 downto 0);
    result_o  : out std_logic

  );
end detect_contiguous;

architecture rtl_detect_contiguous of detect_contiguous is
    
begin
  p_check : process(data_i)
  variable temp_result_v : std_logic;
  variable check_started_v : std_logic;  
  variable ones_ended_v : std_logic;  
  begin
    temp_result_v := '0';
    check_started_v := '0';
    ones_ended_v := '0';
    loop_check : for k in 0 to data_i'high loop
      if data_i(k) = '1' then
        if check_started_v = '0' then
          check_started_v := '1';
          temp_result_v := '1';
        elsif ones_ended_v = '1' then
          temp_result_v := '0';
          exit;       
        end if;
      elsif check_started_v = '1' then
        ones_ended_v := '1';
      end if;
    end loop loop_check;
    result_o <= temp_result_v;
  end process p_check;
end architecture rtl_detect_contiguous;
```

Answer (score 0):

The following assumes VHDL 2008.

You can declare a function for that. Let's start with an easy to understand version:

```vhdl
function is_contiguous(a: std_ulogic_vector) return boolean is
  variable c: natural range 0 to 3 := 0;
begin
  for i in a'range loop
    c := 1 when c = 0 and a(i) = '1' else
         2 when c = 1 and a(i) = '0' else
         3 when c = 2 and a(i) = '1';
  end loop;
  return c /= 3;
end function is_contiguous;
```

We loop over all bits from left to right. The `c` variable (initialized to `0`) takes value `1` when we encounter the first `'1'`, `2` when we encounter the first `'0'` after the first `'1'`, and `3` when we encounter a second `'1'` after that. So, if at the end `c` is different from `3` your vector is *contiguous*. Demo:

```
$ cat foo.vhd
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std_unsigned.all;

entity foo is
end entity foo;

architecture rtl of foo is
  function is_contiguous(a: std_ulogic_vector) return boolean is
    variable c: natural range 0 to 3 := 0;
  begin
    for i in a'range loop
      c := 1 when c = 0 and a(i) = '1' else
           2 when c = 1 and a(i) = '0' else
           3 when c = 2 and a(i) = '1';
    end loop;
    return c /= 3;
  end function is_contiguous;
begin
  process
    variable v: std_ulogic_vector(7 downto 0);
  begin
    for i in 0 to 255 loop
      v := to_stdulogicvector(i, 8);
      report to_string(v) & ": " & to_string(is_contiguous(v));
    end loop;
    wait;
  end process;
end architecture rtl;

$ ghdl -a --std=08 foo.vhd
$ ghdl -r --std=08 foo
foo.vhd:26:7:@0ms:(report note): 00000000: true
foo.vhd:26:7:@0ms:(report note): 00000001: true
foo.vhd:26:7:@0ms:(report note): 00000010: true
foo.vhd:26:7:@0ms:(report note): 00000011: true
foo.vhd:26:7:@0ms:(report note): 00000100: true
foo.vhd:26:7:@0ms:(report note): 00000101: false
foo.vhd:26:7:@0ms:(report note): 00000110: true
foo.vhd:26:7:@0ms:(report note): 00000111: true
foo.vhd:26:7:@0ms:(report note): 00001000: true
foo.vhd:26:7:@0ms:(report note): 00001001: false
foo.vhd:26:7:@0ms:(report note): 00001010: false
foo.vhd:26:7:@0ms:(report note): 00001011: false
...
```

Slightly more elegant but maybe a bit more difficult to understand, you could also write a recursive function by considering that a vector is contiguous if and only if one of the following holds:

- its length is less or equal 2,
- its 2 halves are contiguous and at least one is all zero,
- its 2 halves are contiguous and the 2 joining bits (the rightmost of left half and the leftmost of right half) are ones.

This leads to:

```vhdl
function is_contiguous(a: std_ulogic_vector) return boolean is
  constant n: natural := a'length;
  constant v: std_ulogic_vector(0 to n-1) := a;     -- re-indexing
  constant x: std_ulogic_vector := v(0 to n/2-1);   -- left half
  constant y: std_ulogic_vector := v(n/2 to n-1);   -- right half
  constant z: std_ulogic_vector := v(n/2-1 to n/2); -- joining bits
begin
  return n<=2 or (is_contiguous(x) and is_contiguous(y) and
                  ((or x = '0') or (or y = '0') or (z = "11")));
end function is_contiguous;
```

There are chances that it is also faster after logic synthesis (in `log(n)` instead of `n`).

Answer (score 0):

There is no such function.
I always liked solving problems with functions, but most of the time you have to write them yourself. The most readable solutions are often not as efficient, but depending on synthesis constraints might still be okay.

The [recursive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77177631/6218902) method of Renaud Pacalet looks really nice and efficient.
And i would choose the following (verbose) way for readability:

```vhdl
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std_unsigned.all;

entity foo is
end entity foo;

architecture rtl of foo is
  function rightmost_one(a: std_ulogic_vector) return integer is
    alias v : std_ulogic_vector(a'high downto 0) is a;
    variable result : integer range 0 to v'high := v'high;
  begin
    for idx in v'range loop
      if v(idx) = '1' then
        result := idx;
      end if;
    end loop;
    return result;
  end function;

  function leftmost_one(a: std_ulogic_vector) return integer is
    alias v : std_ulogic_vector(a'high downto 0) is a;
    variable result : integer range 0 to v'high := 0;
  begin
    for idx in v'reverse_range loop
      if v(idx) = '1' then
        result := idx;
      end if;
    end loop;
    return result;
  end function;

  function is_contiguous(a: std_ulogic_vector) return boolean is
    alias v : std_ulogic_vector(a'high downto 0) is a;
    variable left, right : integer range 0 to v'high;
  begin
    left := leftmost_one(v);
    right := rightmost_one(v);
    if (left < right) then
      return true; -- no '1'
    elsif and v(left downto right) then
      return true; -- all '1' in between leftmost and rightmost
    end if;
    return false;
  end function is_contiguous;

begin
  process
    variable v: std_ulogic_vector(7 downto 0);
  begin
    for i in 0 to 255 loop
      v := to_stdulogicvector(i, 8);
      report to_string(v) & ": " & to_string(is_contiguous(v));
    end loop;
    wait;
  end process;
end architecture rtl;
```